# Correct usage of Windows Server on network?

Tags: networking, home-networking, windows-server-2003, dhcp

I have two routers, one with dhcp turned on and the other with it off. this is a functioning home network. Now, I am trying to integrate into it a windows server. Should the windows server be doing the dhcp and dns work? And if so, what will this mean for the existing network? Will I need to reconfigure this? I am currently installing server 2003 onto my server machine. It is connected up to the network on the main router with dhcp. Any words of advice?

Comment: Depends on your needs. If your looking to experiment with AD etc. Then have the DHCP role on your server, and disable it on your router.

Comment: Nthing it depends on what your goal is.